# C++ ShellExecute batch script won't recognize commands

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file

As the title may suggest, i am trying to open a .bat file via "ShellExecute" function.

It works with very basic .bat scripts, such as "hello world" ones, but won't work with others containing commands for running game servers.
For example, here is a batch script for a "Killing Floor 1" server:

```
ucc server KF-Mountainpass.rom?game=KFmod.KFGameType?VACSecured=true?MaxPlayers=6?GamePassword=genrl -log=server.log
PAUSE
```

Please note that this batch works perfectly when manually clicking on it, but gives the following error when opened via ShellExecute:

```
"ucc" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I have also tested on other batch files for other game servers, having the same result.

So, here is a list of what i have tried so far, and did not work:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "cmd.exe", "C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /C C:\\Cartella_Server\\Server_KF1\\System\\KF_Server_Launcher.bat", NULL, SW_SHOW);

ShellExecute(NULL,"open", C:\\Cartella_Server\\Server_KF1\\System\\KF_Server_Launcher.bat", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);

ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "cmd.exe", "/C C:\\Cartella_Server\\Server_KF1\\System\\KF_Server_Launcher.bat", NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

Is there any solution to this?

Thanks in advance for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the script is loading inside the directory of cmd.exe

Why? Because you didn't fill the working directory field.

Have a look at the 5th parameter of ShellExecute:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: So how would the code become? Could you please post the right code? Thank you

Comment: Just pass "C:\\Cartella_Server\\Server_KF1\\System\\" to the 5th parameter :)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the `ucc` program is in the same directory as tha launcher script. So it works when you click on it, because your current directory is one with the file, but when you run your program your current directory is different.

Solution - provide proper directory in fifth ShellExecute argument, as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx